# Why my OpenCL.dll doesn't have clReleaseDevice function?

Tags: windows, dll, opencl, nvidia

I got an error while initializing a device variable.

```
cl::Device device;
```

**Problem:**

> The procedure entry point clReleaseDevice could not be located in the
> dynamic link library OpenCL.dll

I opened OpenCL.dll from `C:\Windows\System32 with "Dependency Walker"` and it really doesn't have such a function. I'm using Windows 7 and NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit 11.5 and cannot run the simplest program.

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`clReleaseDevice` was added in [OpenCL 1.2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf). So, if your OpenCL library does not contain this function it means that the library supports only OpenCL 1.1 or older version. So, you can solve this issue in two ways:

1. Update the OpenCL.dll (for example, the build instruction is available [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-ICD-Loader#build-instructions))
2. Rewrite the sample in accordance with OpenCL 1.1 or older. It looks like you use `cl2.hpp` or `opencl.hpp`, so you can use `CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION` macro to specify the target OpenCL version:

```cpp
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 110
#include <CL/opencl.hpp>
```